# Replace multiple values from date on same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel 2016 spreadsheet has 3 sheets:
Sheet1 (Tab README)
Sheet2 (Tab OTHER NOTES)
Sheet3 (Tab HYPERLINKS)
The spreadsheet may have up 50,000 records.
Column B is populated with different file extensions without the dot beginning at B:3.  Not every cell in ColB has an extension.  The top two rows of my spreadsheet have title information and frozen for viewing when scrolling.

I want to convert these extensions to a descriptive word, e.g., aac, amr, m4p, mp3, pcm to “Audio”, gif, heic, jpg, png, tif to “Image”, etc.

I have a list of extensions on the same spreadsheet: Extensions are J3:J73 with replacement words K3:K73.

When I run the attached VBA, I receive:
Run-time error ‘9:  Subscript out of range
at line
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B1:B8051").Select

This code runs fine on a single-sheet spreadsheet.  I have tried to modify the spreadsheet by making sure there is a extension string in all cells in ColB, and remove the freeze with no change, i.e., same error.

```vb
    Sub Ext2FileType ()
        For i = 3 To 73 'Rows with extension/word J3:K73
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B1:B8051").Select '8051 extensions to convert
            Selection.Replace What:=Cells(i,10).Value, Replacement:=Cells(i, 11).Value, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
        Next
        Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 1).Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: Is Sheet 3 actually called "Sheet3" or "HYPERLINKS" as per your introduction to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using the tab name (`HYPERLINKS`) rather the "true" name, i.e., `Sheet1` did the trick.